# Is there a thermodynamic law or theorem that expresses how systems "break" or "change" when enough energy is added?

Tags: thermodynamics, complex-systems

I have a simple question about thermodynamic laws, and I am hoping you can help me.
Let's say that I have a sphere container with some pressurized gas in it. I can slowly increase the pressure over time, and eventually the container will have to rupture (no matter what it is made of). More generally, if energy is slowly added to a system in a consistent manner, there will be some point in time when the system either changes or breaks as it can no longer contain the energy. Which of the thermodynamic laws would explain this thought experiment?

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Normally these questions are considered by comparing some characteristic length, say the spacing between atoms in the solid, to the length of deformation. When the latter becomes large relative to the former, the thing breaks.

Comment: I cannot tell from the details you give whether that is what you are after, but you question seems to belong to the kind of problems addressed by [catastrophe theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory).